# Using Log when working with a time-series

Tags: finance, time-series

I have a time-series list of stockA, which I call `bas`. I have taken the natural log of `bas` by using

```
LOG[bas]
```

As you you know this gives the natural log of each number in the time-series list. This is what I want to do now

```
OPR = Log[bas/(bas at t-1)]*100
```

How can I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
bas = FinancialData["MSFT", {DatePlus[Date[], -365], Date[]}, "Value"]
(* Here bas is defined as the time-series of prices for Microsoft (ticker: MSFT) *)
```

Now you can compute the log-returns:

```
Differences[Log[bas]]
```

Comment: This was actually done in my class, the teacher stated that you simply take the list of values and then divide that list with the same list at point t-1. I do understand the log of it but I dont understand how t-1 is conducted.

Comment: @ALEXANDER There are many types of returns... nominal return is defined as $R_{t}=\dfrac{P_{t}-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}$. However, log-returns are defined as the logarithm of the price differences (or simply the logarithm of the norminal returns). So, $LogRet_{t}=Log(R_{t})=Log(\dfrac{P_{t}-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}})=Log(\dfrac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}})$

Comment: Okey what if i ask this question. I want to divide list ss of shareprices by list ss of shareprices at time t-1. how would you do this, the teacher talked about the fact that since it is now at t-1 you would lose the value of the first row of the list. Not sure what she meant about that.

Comment: @Alexander That's correct! If you have a price time-series with `n` elements you will always get `n-1` returns. You can check that by using `Length[bas]` and `Length[Differences[Log[bas]]]`. I get 250 prices and 249 returns.

Comment: Okey, sounds good. But how do you subtract one values in one list from the other list?

Comment: @ALEXANDER Remember that $Log(\dfrac{A}{B})=Log(A)-Log(B)$. The `Log` function does the job for you!

Comment: Lets take it from this, I understand LogRet which you postet earlier. the last bit of the formula you posted you divide by P at t-1. I dont understand how to get the list in this format so im able to run that formula.

Comment: Understand what I asked above here?

Comment: @ALEXANDER Suppose `listA={1,3,8}`. If you compute `Differences[listA]` you get `{2,5}`. Got it?

Comment: So basically if I apply the formula that you gave me here I get log return Length[Differences[Log[bas]]] ?

Comment: @ALEXANDER Yes, I'm pretty sure about it... but remember: use only `Differences[Log[bas]]`... `Length` is used only to check how many prices and returns you have in your time-series.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sometimes I think my Iq falls below freezing point! What would I do with out help from you guys! Again thank you so much!